# Column to list of text separated by space

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have excel data that looks like the following:

```
1 A
2 A
3 B
4 B
2 B
1 B
7 B
```

etc... I would like to have a list of the values in column A, separated by a space,  if they all share the same value in column B. For example, if the value in column B is equal to A then I would get "1 2" if it was equal to B then I would get "3 4 2 1 7" etc...
I don't quite know what to do because I have varying quantities of the values in column B...

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make is to misunderstand this is not a service site. We do not provide "ready to use" solutions. This is a Q&A site. There is a reasonable expectation that you will have attempted something before posting. Please share with us what you have attempted and we will try to help you from that point.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
A   B   C       --Columns
1   A   1       - Formula in column C =IF(B1<>B2;A2;C1&" "&A2)
2   A   1 2 
3   B   3   
4   B   3 4 
5   B   3 4 5
```

Or use ConcatenateRange from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-rows-in-a-column-into-one-cell-in-excel) question.

Comment: I never thought about continuing to add on to the string. Simple and genius, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would insert two lines at the top with C1="A", C2="B", etc. for all values of column B.

```
\ | A B C D E
--+---------- 
1 |     A B Y
2 |
3 | 1 A  =C2&IF(C$1=$B3;" "&$A3;"")
4 | 2 A
5 | 3 B
6 | 4 B
7 | 2 B
8 | 1 B
9 | 7 B
```

And then extend the formula in C3 to all cells right and under C3.

Cannot resist: if I had it in CSV on Unix I would have written

```
for i in `sed 's/^.*,//' < file` ; do echo $i : `sed -n "s/,$i,*.*//p" < file` ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, try this small macro:

```
Sub Routine()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v As String, vc As String

    Columns("B:B").Copy Range("C1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To Nc
        v = ""
        vc = Cells(i, "C").Value
        For j = 1 To Na
            If Cells(j, "B").Value = vc Then
                If v = "" Then
                    v = CStr(Cells(j, "A").Value)
                Else
                    v = v & " " & CStr(Cells(j, "A").Value)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, "D").Value = v
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant thank you! I wish I knew how to write macros better... :P

Comment: @Dave ...............practice......practice.............practice